# Magento2 how to get two tables data in my custom grid.?

Tags: php, database, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes, sales-rule

I want to get data as name from salesrule table code from salesrule_coupontable.
Here I attached the salesrule and salesrule_coupon table in which I want to get code column data.

In the salesrule table, I want to get name column data
https://i.imgur.com/WYAHZCz.png

In the salesrule_coupon  table, I want to get code column data.
https://i.imgur.com/TAwPJqF.png

Give a solution for displaying both table columns in my custom grid.
I want that both columns data in my custom grid.
https://i.imgur.com/fUS1qgl.png